# What is the functionality of transform-origin when using scale?

Tags: html, css

I understand how `transform-origin` works when doing rotations, but when I use `scale`, it works differently from my admittedly naive assumption of how it should behave.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/t71f46rb/  I added a transition to help illustrate the effect.

In my mind, when you give a `transform-origin` and then `scale`, the point represented by the `transform-origin` would then be the center of where the scaling took place.  Clearly this isn't the case as the centered version of the reticle in my example never meets the one in the element being scaled.

So, what's actually going on here?  How does `transform-origin` affect a `scale`?  Also, if I wanted that point in the element to be centered during the `scale`, how might I achieve that?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/oXWdRN

Comment: To be honest, i don't seem to understand you testcase. Could you elaborate on this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbRqGo ?

Comment: I'm not using the keywords like top, left, etc.  I'm using an arbitrary point specified by percentages.

Secondly, I'm trying to simulate the action of "zooming in" on a particular point in the element.

Comment: @Paulie_D, I thought I met those requirements.  I expected the two reticles in my example to line up.  They didn't.

Answer (score 0):

transform-origin property defines the starting point for transformation

for eg: for a div of width 200px height 200px and transform-origin:50% 90%(say point x) and scale(2)

it means after transformation div will have width 400px and height 400px and point x will be at 50% left and 90% top of this new div.

Before transformation
[image]
After transformation

[image]

> if I wanted that point in the element to be centered during the scale

then you have to use transform-origin:50% 50%;

let me know if this helps or not